# Set async processing timeout on Tomcat 8.5 / Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, asynchronous

I deploy a Spring MVC webapp on Tomcat 8.5 with the following controller:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class AppController {

    @RequestMapping(value="getOkSync", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody String getOkSync() {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(60000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "ok";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="getOkAsync", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody Callable<String> getOkAsync() {

        return new Callable<String>() {
            @Override
            public String call()  {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(60000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return "ok";
            }
        };
    }

}
```

while the first method returns after 60 sec the correct result, the second method returns after approximately 30 seconds with HTTP response code 500 and the corresponding Spring class logs

```
Could not complete async processing due to timeout or network error.
```

(if the delay is set on the other hand to 20 seconds both metods return "ok" after 20 seconds as expected).
Is the timeout controlled by Spring MVC or by Tomcat? What is the property which controls the timeout?

Comment: In my case TC responded with 503 after 10 seconds and nothing in logs! I don't use MVC so @EnableWebMvc was not needed. Why it is not available through properties?!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the following works (i.e. both methods return now "ok" after 60 seconds), though there is an interaction between Spring and Tomcat which I do not understand completely at the moment (in any case it appears that if I don't set the property via Spring, the timeout will be that of Tomcat, though I don't know how to set the latter)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="my.base.package")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        configurer.setDefaultTimeout(120000);
        super.configureAsyncSupport(configurer);
    }

    ...
```