# Spring Boot Timeout when using Futures

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, future

I am using Spring Boot version 2.0.6.RELEASE

I have the following API method

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/searchData", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Future<List<DataEntryBean>> getSearchData() {

    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {

        List<DataEntryBean> dataList = dataService.getSearchData();

        return dataList;
    });
}
```

The getSearchData method takes around 40 seconds to run.
After 30 seconds, my code times out with the following message displaying in the logs:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.context.request.async.AsyncRequestTimeoutException]
```

And the following json response returns

```
{
  "timestamp": 1544094968149,
  "status": 503,
  "error": "Service Unavailable",
  "message": "No message available",
  "path": "/searchData"
}
```

The getSearchData() method continues to execute and eventually shows in the logs as completing.
If I remove the Future return type and just return a List - the code works fine.
I have tried the following properties but with no success unfortunately.

```
spring.mvc.async.request-timeout=-1
server.connection-timeout=-1
```

Does anyone know what I need to do in order to get this resolved and still allow me to return a Future type?

Thank you
Damien

Comment: Setting the property `spring.mvc.async.request-timeout` works for me, have you restarted the server or are you sure the configuration has been taken into account?

Comment: I have restarted multiple times but it takes no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no timeout settings for a non-async request, so when you remove the future return type, the async request becomes an non-async request, and it just works fine.

`spring.mvc.async.request-timeout` is a timeout setting for async requests.

You could set it to a larger number, say, 60000, or just change the return type.

I don't think that `-1` means no timeout for async request, in fact there is no way to set no timeout for async requests.

Comment: Unfortunately no joy with this approach. Tried your suggestion and I still get the same error

Comment: @Damien could you check the property value at runtime by using `@Value("${spring.mvc.async.request-timeout}")` on a field or from `Environment`?

Comment: tried that and the value I specified is what is returned

Comment: @Damien then I have no idea, I don't know if it's related but I'm using a previous version of Spring Boot.

Comment: what version are you using and I can give it a try?

Comment: @Damien it's 1.4.x

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184818/discussion-between-grape-mao-and-damien).

Comment: @Damien how about a java config way? Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/49136102/5053214

Comment: @Damien There had been an issue about the property file way which was resolved in 1.3.0 milestone, check https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2900

Comment: Unfortunately no joy with the java config approach. I saw that article on the property file way. That property is now listed as a common property in the spring docs

Answer (score 1):

Try setting those two properties to a specific value, like 60 or 120.
Additionaly add `@EnableAsync` to your main class and `@Async` to your method.

Comment: There is no stacktrace. The message I posted above is the only message I get.

Comment: Can you try creating a TaskExecutor bean, maybe there is an issue with the custom one

Comment: Tried that but same results. Thanks for the help so far folks

Comment: Add an exception handler for that exception, then print the stacktrace from it. It should show you then what is the root cause of the issue.